# Coldfusion Search Results Filter with checkboxes and Jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, checkbox, filter, coldfusion

I am developing a website for employment. On the search results page i pass the url variables to a Coldfusion component which returns the results in JSON format and then gets outputted with a handlebars template (thanks to a script by Raymond Camden which can be found [here](http://www.raymondcamden.com/2012/05/11/Using-CFC-data-with-Handlebars)).

I would like to filter the results using checkboxes based on the various categories from my db, there is a PHP tutorial online which does exactly what i would like my search page to do and that can be found [here](http://community.sitepoint.com/t/use-ajax-to-filter-mysql-results-with-multiple-checkbox-option/38018/53)

Here is my is script and the handlebars template:

handlebars template:

```
 <script id="results-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    {{#each records}}

        <div class="search-results">
             <h3 class="text-left">{{job_title}}</h3>
            <ul class="list-group">
                <li class="list-group-item">DATE POSTED: {{job_date_post}}</li>
                <li class="list-group-item">JOB REF NO: {{job_ref_no}}</li>
                <li class="list-group-item">INDUSTRY: {{job_industry}}</li>
                <li class="list-group-item">KEYWORDS: {{job_keywords}}</li>
                <li class="list-group-item">JOB TYPE: {{job_type_id}}</li>
            </ul>
        </div>


    {{/each}}
</script>
```

Here is the ajax call:

```
 <script>
 function cfQueryNormalize(d) {
    var result = [];
    for(var i=0, len=d.DATA.length; i<len;i++) {
        var item = {};
        for(var k=0,innerlen=d.COLUMNS.length; k<innerlen; k++ ) {
            item[d.COLUMNS[k].toLowerCase()] = d.DATA[i][k];
        }
        result.push(item);
    }
    return result;
} 


$(document).ready(function() {

    //Get the contents from the script block 
    var source = document.querySelector("#results-template").innerHTML;
    //Compile that baby into a template
    template = Handlebars.compile(source);



    $.get("cfc/search-results.cfc?method=getresults&returnformat=json", {city:"<cfoutput>#url.city#</cfoutput>", Keywords:"<cfoutput>#url.keywords#</cfoutput>"}, function(res,code) {
        var d = cfQueryNormalize(res);
        var html = template({records:d});
        $("#results").html(html);
    }, "json");

    });

</script>
```

Here is the Coldfusion Component:

```
 <cffunction access="remote" name="getresults" output="false" >

 <cfargument name="city" displayName="city" type="string" hint="Displays the Search Results"  />
 <cfargument name="keywords" displayName="keywords" type="string" hint="Displays the Search Results"  />
 <cfargument name="salary_id" displayName="salary_id" type="string" hint="Displays the Salary Results" />
 <cfargument name="job_type_id" displayname="job_type_id" type="string" required="no">
 <cfargument name="job_industry" displayname="job_industry" type="string" required="no">

 <cfquery name="getresults" datasource="#datasource#" username="#username#" password="#password#">
  SELECT jobs.job_id, 
    jobs.job_title, 
    jobs.job_type_id,
    jobs.job_salary_id, 
    jobs.job_salary, 
    jobs.loc_country, 
    jobs.loc_region, 
    jobs.loc_city, 
    jobs.job_date_post, 
    jobs.job_ref_no, 
    jobs.job_detail_organization, 
    jobs.job_detail_requirements, 
    jobs.job_detail_description, 
    jobs.recruiter_id, 
    jobs.job_industry, 
    jobs.job_sub_industry, 
    jobs.job_keywords, 
    jobs.job_active, 
    jobs.job_applications, 
    jobs.job_views
 FROM jobs
 WHERE <cfif #Arguments.city# GT''>jobs.loc_city = #Arguments.city# AND</cfif> jobs.job_keywords LIKE '%#Arguments.keywords#%' <cfif Isdefined ('Arguments.salary_id')>AND jobs.job_salary_id = #Arguments.salary_id#</cfif>
 </cfquery>

 <cfreturn getresults> 
 </cffunction>
```

My checkboxes will be based on :

1) Salary and they will have a range of yearly salary amounts

2) Job Type - Permanent, Part Time, Tempory etc

3) Job Industry.

The results all have the corresponding checkbox fields in the db.

How would i be able to click on one or more of the checkboxes and refine the results in the Coldfusion component based on the selection i have made?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Tomalak:

here is the code for the one group of checkboxes that i have:

```
 <cfloop query="getstypes">
 <li class="list-group-item">
     <label><input class="job_salary#getstypes.job_salary_id#" type="checkbox" name="salary_id" id="salary_id" value="#getstypes.job_salary_id#"> #getcur.currency_symbol##numberformat(getstypes.job_salary_from, ",")#to #getcur.currency_symbol##numberformat(getstypes.job_salary_to, ",")#<span>(#getscount.recordcount#)</span></label>
     </li>

 </cfloop>
```

Could you advise if this is correct please?

Comment: It looks like you are grabbing all the records from the db matching the city/keywords/salary_id passed in. Do you then want to filter that result set further based on clicking checkboxes? If so then I'd consider filtering the recordset you already have in the browser with JS rather than repeatedly looking up the records from the database. BTW well worth reading up on SQL injection attacks and cfqueryparam :)

Comment: Is there any way of having the user enter his filters earlier in the process?

Comment: Hi John, thanks for getting back to me. The main search is for keywords and then the user can select country and city, if those are blank then it will load all jobs for that country. I would like to filter the recordset  returned from the primary search using JS.

Comment: Hi Dan, thanks for getting back to me. My client wants the primary search to be with keywords and then filter the results using Salary Job Type and Industry if that makes sense.

Comment: It does not make sense.  Searching on keywords and url variables is an odd combination.  Do you have a form with method = "get"?

Comment: Hi Dan, yes the method is get, il change it to post

Comment: No, don't change it to POST. If your CFC function does not *change* data, but only *reads* data, then GET is the right HTTP method.

Comment: ok il leave it as is

Answer (score 1):

First off, please fix your CFC.

- use typed parameters (i.e. not `string` when they are in fact numeric)
- add parameter sanity checking (range / format checks)
- provide useful defaults for the optional parameters (in fact, you don't really need optional parameters anyway)
- use `<cfqueryparam>` instead of variable interpolation into the SQL text
- define `returnformat="json"` right in the `<cffunction>`

then, in JavaScript:

```
// collect other API methods here, if there are any
var API = {
    getresults: function(params) {
        return $.get("cfc/search-results.cfc?method=getresults", params)
        .then(cfQueryNormalize)
        .fail(function () {
            console.error("getresults failed:" , arguments);
        });
    }
};

$(function() {
    var resultsTemplate = Handlebars.compile($("#results-template").text());

    // on change of any of these input elements...
    $("#city,#keywords,#salary_id,#job_type_id,#job_industry").change(function () {
        // ...call the API with all values and render the result
        API.getresults({
            city: $("#city").val(), 
            keywords: $("#keywords").val(), 
            salary_id: $("#salary_id").val(),
            job_type_id: $("#job_type_id").val(),
            job_industry: $("#job_industry").val()
        })
        .then(renderWith(resultsTemplate))
        .done(function (html) {
            $("#result").html(html);
        });
    });

    // trigger change event once to force initial loading
    $("#city").trigger("change");
});

// helper functions ------------------------------------------------
function cfQueryNormalize(queryObject) {
    return queryObject.DATA.map(function (row) {
        var item = {};
        queryObject.COLUMNS.forEach(function (col, c) {
            item[col.toLowerCase()] = row[c];
        });
        return item;
    });
} 

function renderWith(template) {
    return function (data) {
        return template(data);
    };
}
```

Create the appropriate form fields in your HTML source.

Instead of writing `#url.city#` to your JS source code, write it to the value attribute of your `city` form field. (Create hidden form fields if a value is not meant to be user-changeable.)

Recommended reading to understand `.then()`, `.done()` and `.fail()` I am using in the above code: [jQuery Deferred objects](https://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) and [jQuery ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

Comment: Hi Tomalak i have just added the code for the salary checkboxes above.

Comment: Element KEYWORDS is undefined in ARGUMENTS. and salary_id is constantly 1 even when its not selected,

Comment: I cannot give you code that you can copy and paste into your project and that magically starts to work. I also will not go through a kind of "interactive debugging session" with you here in the comments. The code in my answer is meant to be a nudge into the right direction. It's still your task to *understand* it and make to the necessary changes yourself.

Comment: I appreciate you helping me out with this code, i am not asking for it to be hand written for me, while is has put me in the right direction i was just letting you know what was happening, thanks for your help

Comment: Don't get me wrong, I just want to prevent being drowned in follow-up questions. It happens too often. First thing to do is to get your server side API right. You can use the [Advanced REST client](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-rest-client/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo) to run all kinds of HTTP requests. Once it responds to all parameter combinations with the right data, you can write the JS code in the spirit of my answer.

Comment: Nicely done Tom, plus 1! @johnnyc0506 dipping in for a second to point out that tom's suggestions are mostly going to help your application run smoother, but `<cfqueryparam'ing>` all `#dynamicvariables#` in all your queries should **always** be done and is always critical. It's your primary line of defense against the easiest form of "hacking", **sql injection**.

Comment: @cfqueryparam i have changed all my vars to be <cfqueryparam>